# Does Lambda@Edge retry upon failure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Does Lambda@Edge retry upon failure, or does it return a 500 exception immediately?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any retry mechanism. Lambda@edge is invoked **synchronously**. Retries are associated with asynchronous invocations. Since its synchronous invocation, its generally up to your application to take care of any errors and retries on them.